# How to convert TradingView Pine Script code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pine-script

There are some indicators on TradingView website that are in pine script and I like to add them to chart library so I have them on my website.
But I've done a lot of search, and didn't find how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is on of those indicators that I like to convert to JavaScript:

```html
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo
//@version=4

study("Nadaraya-Watson Estimator [LUX]",overlay=true,max_lines_count=500,max_bars_back=500)
h = input(8.,'Bandwidth')
src = input(close,'Source')
//----
n = bar_index
var ln = array.new_line(0) 
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
float y2 = na
float y1 = na
float y1_d = na
//----
line l = na
label lb = na
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to min(499,n-1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        for j = 0 to min(499,n-1)
            w = exp(-(pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        y2 := sum/sumw
        d = y2 - y1

        l := array.get(ln,i)
        line.set_xy1(l,n-i+1,y1)
        line.set_xy2(l,n-i,y2)
        line.set_color(l,y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14)
        line.set_width(l,2)
        
        if d > 0 and y1_d < 0
            label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=#39ff14,textalign=text.align_center) 
        if d < 0 and y1_d > 0
            label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=#ff1100,textalign=text.align_center) 

        y1 := y2
        y1_d := d
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I doubt you can, it’s especially designed to run on their servers “Pine is cloud-based and therefore different in nature to client-side programming languages.”

Answer (score 3):

There is no converter for such things. Pine Language has nothing to do with JavaScript, so you will need to write your own implementation for each function.

Comment: Yes I know, one of my Colleagues has write an JS implementation for one of indicators
But he spent one week to do that.
My problem is if I can find a documentation for this so I can find equivalent Pine Script function on JS.

Comment: @yaghoob_pr Hi, docs here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no converter for that. TradingView had provide a way to write custom indicators code using javascript.
The guide link is below.

https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Creating-Custom-Studies

You can write your PineJs logic in javascript easily.

Comment: I tried a lot 
for the example above, what is the equivalent for line.set_xy1() in javascript?